# finite transcendence degree and algebraic closure

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory

Let $k$ be an algebraically closed field. Let $K$ be an extension field of $k$ of finite transcendence degree over $k$. Intuitively, it seems to me that $K$ can not be algebraically closed. Is there a proof of that fact or a counterexample?

Comment: For formal power series, we have "if K is an algebraically closed field of characteristic zero, then the field of Puiseux series over K is the algebraic closure of the field of formal Laurent series over K"

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Lets just take a simple example.

$k(t)$ is not algebraically closed. For example, it doesn't have $\sqrt{t}$. (it has trdeg 1)

The algebraic closure $\overline{k(t)}$ of $k(t)$ has finite transcendence degree (ie, 1). This follows from the definition of transcendence degree, since of course $\overline{k(t)}/k(t)$ is algebraic.

Comment: The complex numbers have trdeg 0 over the reals. $\mathbb{C}/\mathbb{R}$ is an algebraic extension of degree 2.

Look up the wikipedia definition of transcendence degree. The extension $k(t)/k$ has a transcendence basis of 1 element, namely $\{t\}$.

Comment: The structure of $\overline{k(t)}$ is not easy to concretely describe. Its elements are basically just roots of polynomials over $k(t)$. Some of these can be viewed as power series in $t$, most can't.